# ToolTip is Taking Too Long To Hide

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

In that form, I am showing a tooltip when the mouse hovers over a button. The tooltip displays until the mouse leaves the button.

The issue is, that when the mouse leaves the button, the tooltip fade time is a little to long. How do I change the tool tip's hide time.

I hide the tooltip via the Hide() function:

```
toolTip.Hide();
```

Comment: WPF, windows forms ?

Comment: Sorry, I will add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the tooltip's AutoPopDelay property to suit your needs.

You can read more about it here (with an example):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.autopopdelay(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was using that, but I don't think I was reducing the number significantly enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `AutoPopDelay` property.

EDIT: The value is in milliseconds

Comment: That's a very informally named property!